# Insert data to table at once which retrieve from mySQL select command

Tags: php, mysql

I have mentioned my Original transaction table and temporary Transaction Table I want to insert data to temporarytransaction table which I select values of Transaction table

```
    CREATE TABLE Transaction(
    Tid int auto_increment primary key,
    T_type varchar(20),
    Amount decimal(10,2),
    Tdate DATETIME,
    accountNo int,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(AccountNo) REFERENCES Account(AccountNo)
    ); 



CREATE TABLE tempTransaction(
    Tid int auto_increment primary key,
    T_type varchar(20),
    Amount decimal(10,2),
    Tdate DATETIME,
    accountNo int,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(AccountNo) REFERENCES Account(AccountNo)
    );
```

> I want edit this query to working one That is my Question

```
INSERT INTO temporarytransaction VALUES (SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE `Tdate` BETWEEN "2012-03-15" AND "2016-03-31");
```

Comment: You call the table `tempTransaction` when you create it, and `temporarytransaction` in your insertion query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the `values()` in; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html.

```
INSERT INTO temporarytransaction SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE `Tdate` BETWEEN "2012-03-15" AND "2016-03-31";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO temporarytransaction (Tid,T_type,Amount,Tdate,accountNo)
SELECT Tid,T_type,Amount,Tdate,accountNo 
FROM Transaction 
WHERE `Tdate` BETWEEN "2012-03-15" AND "2016-03-31"
```